# redirect for a just rewrited url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

i've got this sample rule:

```
RewriteRule ^stories\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)+ stories/index.cfm?id=$1
```

and this works perfect.

now, i would redirect one page (just rewrited) to another:

```
Redirect 301 /stories/2000/title-of-stories http://host/stories/2001/another-stories
```

but apache redirect to

```
http://host/stories/2001/another-stories?id=2000
```

appending to url the query string "?id=2000"

how can i remove it?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the RewriteRule is being applied after the Redirect.

Best practice is not to mix directives from the mod_rewrite (RewriteRule) and mod_alias (Redirect). The order in which they are applied is not based on the order that your write the rules, but on the order that the modules are loaded.

In this case, replacing the Redirect 301 directive with an equivalent RewriteRule would be the best option. I haven't tested this, but  something like this might work for you. Note, that you should put your most specific rule first:

```
RewriteRule ^/stories/2000/title-of-stories$ /stories/2001/another-stories [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/stories/([0-9]+)/(.*)+ /stories/index.cfm?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: barryj, this it's simply ingenious :-)
works great! many thanks :-)

Comment: @Roberto, glad that works for you - you might mark my answer correct.

Comment: done :-)